# <TD> and <table> width is broken?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have very strange problem.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3W4X/

Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/H3W4X/embedded/result/

This code:

```
<div id="workspace"> 
       <table id="leds" >
            <tbody id="leds_body">
            </tbody>
       </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#workspace{
position:absolute;
left:200px;
width:760px;
height:600px;
background:#0FF;
float:left;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
background-image: url("bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#leds
{    
position:relative;
left:10px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var WH=10;
$(function(){
    $("#zoom-in").click(function(){
        $(".LED, .NOT_LED").width((WH+1)+"px").height((WH+1)+"px");
        WH=WH+1;
        });

    $("#zoom-out").click(function(){
        $(".LED, .NOT_LED").width((WH-1)+"px").height((WH-1)+"px");
        if (WH==5) WH=5;
        else WH=WH-1;

});
});
```

What I want: Zoom in/out my table (by changing `<td>` size).
What is going on: when I use zoom-in table is 'growing' right, but only to 656px width, then width is staying on 656px and height is still growing. When I checked this in Chrome inspect I saw that table has static 656px. I can change it too higher but its not what I want.
How to make width same as height but not static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `#leds` table is defaulting to `width: 100%`, so your `td` elements are "fitting" to the width. I couldn't figure out a simple CSS-only solution; however, you can set the width each time you click on the `+` or `-` signs:

```
$(function(){
    $("#zoom-in").click(function(){
        $(".LED, .NOT_LED").width(WH+1).height(WH+1);
        $('#leds').width($('#leds_body tr:eq(0) td').length * WH);
        WH=WH+1;
        });

    $("#zoom-out").click(function(){
        $(".LED, .NOT_LED").width((WH-1)+"px").height((WH-1)+"px");
        $('#leds').width($('#leds_body tr:eq(0) td').length * WH);
        if (WH==5) WH=5;
        else WH=WH-1;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H3W4X/3

http://jsfiddle.net/H3W4X/3/embedded/result/

Comment: It's working but it deform my table from square to rectangle :/

Comment: I must not be taking into account some other spacing element like borders or whatnot. Play around with the calculation based on that and it should fix it.